# adding logo to my rails app from my app/assets/images

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, tailwind-css

I am working on my intagram-clone app with rails & tailwind css. I have managed to create a navbar,I am trying to add a logo to the left of the "navbar" but  when I run it locally, the image is not loading.

my navbae.html.erb :

```
<nav class="flex justify-between items-center">
  <a href=<%= root_path %>>
  <%= image_tag "/images/logo.png" %>
  </a>  
  <div>
    <% if user_signed_in?%>
        <a><%= link_to"Home", root_path, class: "text-lg no-underline text-grey-darkest hover:text-blue-dark ml-2"%> <i class="fas fa-home"></i></a>
        <a><%= link_to"My profile", profile_path(current_user.username), class: "text-lg no-underline text-grey-darkest hover:text-blue-dark ml-2"%> <i class="far fa-user"></i> </a>
        <a><%= link_to"New Post",new_post_path, class: "text-lg no-underline text-grey-darkest hover:text-blue-dark ml-2"%> <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i></a>
        <a><%= link_to "log out", destroy_user_session_path,method: :delete, class: "text-lg no-underline text-grey-darkest hover:text-blue-dark ml-2" %> <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></a>
        <%else%>
    <a><%= link_to "sign up", new_user_registration_path,class: "text-lg no-underline text-grey-darkest hover:text-blue-dark ml-2" %> <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i></a>
    <a><%= link_to "sign in", new_user_session_path,class: "text-lg no-underline text-grey-darkest hover:text-blue-dark ml-2" %><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></a>
  <%end%>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your logo is at this path `app/assets/images/logo.png`, you should maybe do

```
<%= image_tag 'logo.png' %>
```